# htaccess remove .php and keep query string issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an endpoint here:

```
https://example.com/api/apitest/api-getinfo.php
```

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/apitest/getinfo/(.*)$ /api/apitest/api-getinfo.php?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

<filesMatch "\.( jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

I don't really understand rewrites but this is what I've wanted:

```
https://example.com/api/apitest/getinfo/John
```

It's working but the URL rewrite ends up looking like this:

```
https://example.com//api/apitest/api-getinfo.php/John/?name=John
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something here but I'm stumped!

Comment: If you don’t understand what’s going on, enable rewrite logging and check …

Comment: Don't you need access to the VirtualHost configuration for that? I don't have access to do that.

Comment: Do you know what these parts do :: $1 :: {QUERY_STRING} :: ?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. I contracted a .htaccess dev to help me with this. This is what he gave me after giving him the spec but he's gone silent.